# Laravel Non-static method issue

Tags: php, model, laravel, non-static

Having the following Models:

**news.php**

```
class News extends Aware {

    public static $table = 'noticia';
    public static $key = 'idnoticia';
    public static $timestamps = false;

    public static $rules = array(
        'titulo' => 'required',
        'subtitulo' => 'required',
    );

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Image');
    }
}
```

**image.php**

```
class Image extends Aware {

    public static $timestamps = true;

    public static $rules = array(
        'unique_name' => 'required',
        'original_name' => 'required',
        'location' => 'required',
        'news_id' => 'required',
    );

    public function news()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('News');
    }

}
```

Then in a controller I do the following:

```
$image = new Image(array(
    'unique_name' => $fileName,
    'original_name' => $file['file']['name'],
    'location' => $directory.$fileName,
    'news_id' => $news_id,
));
News::images()->insert($image);
```

I keep getting the following error message:

> Non-static method News::images() should not be called statically,
>   assuming $this from incompatible context

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Setting `public static function images()` doesn't seem to be wanted, as after a refresh I get an error saying

> $this when not in object context

Gordon said that by doing `News::images()->insert($image);` I'm doing a static call, but that's how saw to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing some steps.

The Image belongs to News, but you're not referencing the News post you want to update.
You probably want to do:

```
$image = new Image(array(...));
$news = News::find($news_id);
$news->images()->insert($image);
```

More in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent).

Answer (score 3):

You're using `$this` in a function that is called `static`ally. That's not possible.

`$this` becomes available only after you create an instance with `new`.

If you turn on strict mode you will get another error, namely that `images` is not a static function and thus shouldn't be called statically.

The problem is in `News::images()`, not in `images()->insert($image);`

Comment: same as I told Martin, I know that... I tried that as I was told to do so, even though knowing that would have the mentioned issue.

Answer (score 1):

$this can only be used within an object instance.
Class::method() calls a static method of the specified class.

In your case, you mixed both.

Your function definition for images is for an object instance:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->has_many('Image');
}
```

You are calling it as a static method:

```
News::images()->insert($image);
```

The `News` class would need to be instantiated or the images method be modified to support static calls.

Comment: if you didn't notice... I said that I had tried using `public static...` as I was recommended to do so, but obviously would have the mentioned issue

Comment: Yeah, hence why I mentioned you can only use `$this` within an object instance.